# Using GPG-agent, the ssh-agent does not show the keys using "ssh-add -l"

Tags: ssh, linux-mint, gpg, ssh-agent, gpg-agent

I've been trying to get a yubikey to work as an authentication method for remote connections via ssh using [this](https://www.isi.edu/~calvin/yubikeyssh.htm#signed-ssh-keys) guide. I got the gpg2 set up nicely, and I can see that i've loaded the key onto the card by

```
gpg2 --card-status
```

I've exported it using

```
gpg2 --export-ssh-key > [keyname].txt
```

and can see the resulting key nicely. I've got my gpg-agent.conf set up as follows :

```
#config pinentry-program
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry

#ssh support
enable-ssh-support

#write env inf to .gpg-agent-info
write-env-file
use-standard-socket

#default cache timeout
default-cache-ttl 600
max-cache-ttl 7200
```

and have modified my .bashrc as given in the guide.
Any ideas where I might look for a solution?

Comment: Isn't it more important to test the connection - does it connect? The troubleshooting section suggest to kill the ssh-agent and start the gpg-agent and create a .plist file.

Comment: @MichaelD. not sure I'm following you - I'm pretty new to linux platforms and I'm going through a lot of new information. What do you mean by test the connection? Connection between what exactly? If it's ssh to the other machine, that works fine. I tried killing the ssh-agent but I'm pretty unsure on how to proceed.

Comment: Okay - I got it working. The problem was probably the SSH_AUTH_SOCK not pointing to my gpg-agent.ssh , which I resolved by forcing the address in .bashrc.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I got it working after tinkering for a while and reading the gpg-agent manpage [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/gpg-agent.1.html). I needed to add

```
unset SSH_AGENT_PID
     if [ "${gnupg_SSH_AUTH_SOCK_by:-0}" -ne $$ ]; then
       export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="${HOME}/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh"
     fi
```

to my .bashrc for the SSH_AUTH_SOCK to point to the correct place instead of the ssh-agent.